# writing dictionary to csv leading to value error

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
details = {"Primary_key" : [{'key_1': 'val', 'key_2': 'val', 'key_3': "val", 'key_4': '2016', 'key_5': ['val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3'], 'key_6': 'val'}, {'key_1': 'val', 'key_2': 'val', 'key_3': 'val', 'key_4': 'val', 'key_5': ['val_1','val_2'], 'key_6': 'val'}, {'key_1': 'val', 'key_2': 'val', 'key_3': 'val', 'key_4': 'val', 'key_5': ['val_1', 'val_2'], 'key_6': 'val'}] }
```

.

I'm trying to write this into a csv file, with the headers as the keys. Here is the code I'm using:

```
 with open("json_test.csv",'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames= ["key_1","key_2","key_3","key_4","key_5","key_6"])
    writer.writeheader()
    for d in details:
        writer.writerow(d)
```

How do I get the following csv format?

[image: Desired csv format]

Comment: Your dictionary isn't formatted properly, is there suppose to be a bracket after details[0]["degrees"]?  And then details[1] will have the key summary that details[0] didn't?

Comment: Yes, "degrees" is the key which has list as the value. Also, the presence of additional key "summary" in details[1] is the problem.

Comment: @hiro protagonist. I pasted it from my console. I must've missed the parenthesis while editing it.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

details = {"Primary_key" : [{'key_1': 'val', 'key_2': 'val', 'key_3': "val", 'key_4': '2016', 'key_5': ['val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3'], 'key_6': 'val'}, {'key_1': 'val', 'key_2': 'val', 'key_3': 'val', 'key_4': 'val', 'key_5': ['val_1','val_2'], 'key_6': 'val'}, {'key_1': 'val', 'key_2': 'val', 'key_3': 'val', 'key_4': 'val', 'key_5': ['val_1', 'val_2'], 'key_6': 'val'}] }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(details["Primary_key"])
df.index = ["primary_key"]*len(df)
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

output.csv:

```
# %load output.csv
,key_1,key_2,key_3,key_4,key_5,key_6
primary_key,val,val,val,2016,"['val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3']",val
primary_key,val,val,val,val,"['val_1', 'val_2']",val
primary_key,val,val,val,val,"['val_1', 'val_2']",val
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried appending using the following
 `for name, val in details.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(details[name])
    df.index = [name]*len(df)
    with open("lrequired.csv",'a') as f:
        df.to_csv(f)`
But everytime the header gets updated too, if I use Header=False, the header is missing. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Joe how about use ind,(name,val) in enumerate(details.items()): .... if ind != 0 df.to_csv(header=False)

Comment: Or add the dfs to a list_ = []. list_.append(df), pd.concat([i for i in list_]) and then output. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The keys in "details" are inconsistent. Each primary key has a maximum of 6 keys, but some are having 1, 2 or 3 keys, this is leading to discrepancy in data. The append function didn't work because of this.

Comment: @Joe Ok, that makes sense. So either first read it to a pandas and do some operations or maybe consider saving in another format like json maybe?